# Android: Is there a way to make SharedPreferences secret/hidden from user? Avoid being manipulated or edited

Tags: android

Is there any way to make SharedPreferences hidden/secret/private from user?

I mean so that user cannot edit or manipulate them?

I was going to store userID after he logins for first time and then avoid logging in every time app is launched but I realized that userID can be easily changed and user could use other users account easily.

So any way to prevent user from editing them?

Comment: arleitiss, if I got it right (I hope I didn't) you are trying to use the user device as the sole repository for the authentication data (!!!). Please *don't do it*: besides the theoretical reasons why it *must not be done*, from a very simple and practical standpoint your users can have anything from a rooted phone to an emulator and read/write **whatever they please** from the device. Use a shared secret, as akash93 suggested, so whatever the user does, he can at most scramble his own credentials.

Comment: @Rick77 yeah I just realized that, I only have 4 months left to finish the app so I don't have much time to learn about AccountManager unfortunetely so I am thinking of quick but safe enough solution. I am planning to use Android DeviceID and store it on my online database after users first login. If at any given point Online-Stored DeviceId is mismatching with person trying to access account from device - it will request login again.

Comment: better, and I understand your hurry (we all are in such situations, from time to time. Or most of the time...) but at this point, why not just let your server return a random token at login, as akash suggested, and save it in the `SharedPreference` plain and simple? It would be *safe* **and** *easy*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MODE_PRIVATE` to make sure that the preferences cannot be accessed by other apps. However I would suggest that instead of using the userid as an authentication mechanism you generate an auth token and store that in your server side database and use that for authentication purposes.

Comment: Files on internal storage, including `SharedPreferences`, are `MODE_PRIVATE` by default, and using mode flags is officially deprecated IIRC.