# How to retrieve in-app purchases and unlock premium version of my app?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have an android app featuring some in-app products. Users buy the in-app product and the app unlocks the corresponding feature(s). Now I have a question: I read the Google documentation and doesn't seem to be a definitive answer to my problem:

The app retrieves the list of available in-app products at startup, then it proceeds to retrieve the list of purchased in-app products. If an in-app product shows up in the available list, then I unlock the feature.

**Why I check the list of available in-app products at startup?**

Because I need to write the prices on the UI (purchase button) and I don't want to hard code all the possible prices for different countries. The response has the list of all the available in-app products plus prices already localized so it's very convenient

**Why I check the list of purchased in-app product at startup?**

Because I want to check if the user has purchased an in-app product and then I unlock the features on the UI. The Google documentations says that the call doesn't require an internet connection so why not? Why bother saving the in-app JSON product locally when I just call the local Google Play API?

Now my problem is: the call to the available in-app products and the call to the purchased products may fail... and in fact it failed once. If it fail what should I do? Keep the features disabled is not an option because the user may think he/she lost the product. Enabling the features is also a no-no because I may enable features to people who never bought the products. So I'm stuck. Is a retry enough? what's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As I understand it:**

The user buys an in-app product which enabled the premium version of your app. Once purchased, no further purchases are required for the feature to be enabled. So it is a one-time purchase.

**Fixing your problem:**

At the moment you always try to get the state of the premium feature at the start of the app using the Google API.

You could also do it like this:
If the user buys the premium feature, save this as a SharedPreference.
Example: premiumVersion = true

Whenever the user returns and the app starts, you could first check the SharedPreference because this is very unlikely to fail (No internet connection required etc.). If premiumVersion == true, then don't ask the Google API for the current state. Only use the Google API if premiumVersion == false. In this case, a previous attempt might have failed, or the user just doesn't have the premium feature.

Sidenote: If the premiumVersion == true, make sure you never override it with false!

**For displaying the prices:**

If anything goes wrong when trying to retrieve your products, just prompt an error message to the user with a message that something went wrong and he should retry it.

Comment: Ok but saving a flag on my local sqlite database is really a bad idea, it's really easy to unlock the app. What about an automatic retry of, lets say, 3 times and then give up and show an error message if I get an error 3 times in a row?

Comment: As I said you can use SharedPreferences, not a Sqlite database. You can secure your SharedPreferences, so they can not be manipulated. Refer to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27756458/2734302)

You can of course implement a retry-system and let the user know if something went wrong.

Comment: can i use firebase as i answered below?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use Fire-base login & realtime database with field premium_enabled - true/false (this will help if user goes for another mobile with old google id for Play-store)

step wise

1. add google login in your App.
2. make an entry of user in fire-base user_id/email_id and premium_enabled field and store data in it. (you can add fields as per your requirement)

   if user purchased than make an entry 
         premium_enabled - true & also use shared preference for offline check